# Changing ID of dynamically added SVG object can only be read in event if 'alert' called beforehand

Tags: javascript, svg, dom-events

I need help with a specific Javascript question that I have spent hours working on and now stuck. I'm also new to Javascript and have a .NET background.

My application consists of widgets coded up in separate SVG files which contain inline JS functions to manipulate the widget (like rotation). I want to drag/drop these SVG widgets from a library popup onto the main page. I want the widgets to be in separate files so that end users can add or remove widget files as needed.

The SVG widgets are dynamically added to the main page HTML as objects and I can get the object to display and I can interact with the Javascript in the SVG. I also dynamically change the ID of the SVG `<g>` tag that wraps the SVG so that I can uniquely identify the widget on the page.

I'd like to use HTML5 drag/drop feature however I can't work out how to extract the SVG id name from the event object that gets passed into the dragstart event handler (so I can save the object id in the datatransfer object for use afterwards). I'm aware that you can't attach events to object tags so I use an ID on the `<g>` tag in the SVG, and can invoke the dragstart event when dragging the svg object. Interestingly if I don't add the SVG dynamically I can extract the `<g>` ID from  `event.currentTarget.parentWindow.gID.id` but when added dynamically the gID is null in the event object.

Even weirder is if I add an alert after I change the ID of the SVG `<g>` tag then I can get the ID from the event object. So there must be some sort of timing issue but I don't understand why, as the alert that makes the script work is **before** I change the ID of the SVG `<g>`. I also use a load event on the SVG to ensure the SVG is properly loaded before setting properties.

Code:

```
    var svgDialObj
    var svgDialDoc
    var svgDialWin
    window.onload = function () {               // Startup function after DOM is loaded 
            var object2 = document.createElement("object");
            object2.type = "image/svg+xml";
            object2.data = "dial.svg"
            object2.className = "widget"
            object2.id = "svgDial1";
            object2.draggable = "true"
            document.getElementById('container').appendChild(object2);
            svgDialObj = document.getElementById("svgDial1");
            svgDialObj.addEventListener("load", function () { // access properties once the file is loaded
                svgDialDoc = svgDialObj.contentDocument;
                var oldDialID = svgDialDoc.getElementById("svgDial");
                alert(oldDialID.id);    // EVENT OBJECT ONLY WORKS IF THIS ALERT IS INSERTED HERE
                oldDialID.setAttribute("id", "svgDial1");
                svgDialWin = svgDialDoc.defaultView;
                svgDialDoc.addEventListener('dragstart', drag_start, false);
            }, false);
        }

    function drag_start(event) {
        alert(event.currentTarget.parentWindow.gID.id);   // fails with null if I don't use the alert before setting the event handler
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.currentTarget.parentWindow.gID.id + ',' + event.clientX + ',' + event.clientY);
    }
```

SVG

```
 <svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onload="startup(evt)">
   <g id="svgDial" transform="">
     <path id="seg1" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 134, 0)" d="M13.46,66.27 A40,40,0,0,1,10.1,52.79" stroke-width="20" />
     <path id="seg2" fill="none" stroke="rgb(50, 134, 0)" d="M10.01,50.7 A40,40,0,0,1,12.18,36.98" stroke-width="20" />
     <path id="seg3" fill="none" stroke="rgb(100, 134, 0)" d="M12.91,35.02 A40,40,0,0,1,20.27,23.23" stroke-width="20" />
     <path id="seg4" fill="none" stroke="rgb(150, 134, 0)" d="M21.72,21.72 A40,40,0,0,1,33.1,13.75" stroke-width="20" />
     <path id="seg5" fill="none" stroke="rgb(200, 134, 0)" d="M35.02,12.91 A40,40,0,0,1,48.6,10.02" stroke-width="20" />
     <path id="seg6" fill="none" stroke="rgb(255, 134, 0)" d="M50.7,10.01 A40,40,0,0,1,64.33,12.66" stroke-width="20" />
     <path id="seg7" fill="none" stroke="rgb(255, 100, 0)" d="M66.27,13.46 A40,40,0,0,1,77.79,21.23" stroke-width="20" />
     <path id="seg8" fill="none" stroke="rgb(255, 70, 0)" d="M79.25,22.72 A40,40,0,0,1,86.82,34.37" stroke-width="20" />
     <path id="seg9" fill="none" stroke="rgb(255, 35, 0)" d="M87.59,36.32 A40,40,0,0,1,90,50" stroke-width="20" />
     <path id="seg10" fill="none" stroke="rgb(255, 0, 0)" d="M89.95,52.09 A40,40,0,0,1,86.82,65.63" stroke-width="20" />
     <path id="needle" fill="rgb(100, 100, 100)" stroke="rgb(90, 90, 90)" stroke-width="2" d="M24.39,54.51 A26,26,0,1,1,27.48,63 l-20,4 Z" />
     <text id="numVal" x="34" y="58" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 24px; text-align: center">0.0</text>
   </g>
 <script>
    <![CDATA[
     ...
     //]]>
 </script>
</svg>
```

Questions:

1. What is the timing error I have here and how do I avoid it?
2. I don't really understand the DOM yet - is the `event.currentTarget.parentWindow.gID.id` the right way to extract a unique identifier from the event? (I assume I can't from the HTML object and have to reach into the SVG)
3. Is the object tag the best way to include external SVG files with Javascript?
4. Although HTML5 drag / drop should work - would I be better off using a library like Jquery for drag/drop support or implement manual drag/drop support through mousedown / mouseup event handler for this scenario?
5. I am very new to JavaScript so if there is anything else dumb I have done in the code please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to get id (without alert), the new  is not yet rendered.
so you need to add the code after svgDialObj.addEventListener("load", function () { in
setTimeout invoking it after 100ms or so.

that should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Mukesh. Is there a more synchronous way of waiting for the update to 'stick'? Adding a specific delay could be brittle on a slower client and also adds a lag to the UI. Is this typical in javascript where changes take a delay before being rendered? Or is there a 'change' event that I could wait for?

Comment: Marked as answer as it does indeed work as Mukesh described. However I'd still be interested if there is a change ready event or similar that could be used to be more precise than adding a delay.

Comment: Delay will not create any problem here.
setTimeout will only get executed once onload method finishes irrespective of time specified.
please check following post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368655/javascript-in-browser-asynchronous-tasks-execution-model

Comment: Yes, I changed the timeout to 1msec and it still works, and only need to add the code that modifies the SVG ID in the setTimeout. Thanks for the link, it helps me understand the javascript execution model. I would upvote the reply but I'm still new to stackoverflow.